# Spark join removes joining columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have 2 datasets on which I am performing join. Dataset merc and ded both have same schema.

> Schema :id, mid, pid, zid

```
List<String> joinSeqList = Lists.newArrayList("id","mid");
Dataset<Row> dataDF = merc.as("merc")
                .join(ded.as("ded"),
                        convertListToSeq(joinSeqList),
                        "fullouter");

private Seq<String> convertListToSeq(List<String> inputList) {
        return scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(inputList).seq();
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that the resulting schema has all the columns of `merc` but not  all columns of `ded`. id and mid from ded are not there in final schema (which are the join columns).

Since I am getting all columns of `merc`, how can I get to have all columns of `ded` as well.

So output should contain all columns of `merc` and `ded`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve using below join condition

```
Dataset<Row> dataDF =  merc.as("merc")
            .join(ded.as("ded"),col("merc.id").equalTo(col("ded.id")).and(
                                              col("merc.mid").equalTo(col("ded.mid"))), "outer");
```